# Google Apps Script showing 'This app is not verified' on my own private script

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Basically as the title describes: I have a script created in a Google Sheet that attempts to access my own Gmail account. The script will never be public and serves a function that's only useful to me. I know Google tightened security last year, but surely I don't need to get my private app verified when it'll only be used in the same account as it was created?

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: You do not need to get it verified by Google if using it privately, but you will receive the 'This app is not verified' the first time you try running your script. Unless you make further changes to the OAuth scopes, you will not need to authorize it again.

Comment: Further details can be found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification

Comment: "you will not need to authorize it again" - unfortunately this is not true, otherwise there'd be no issue. This verification nonsense keeps popping up regularly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click '**Advanced**' 
   [image]
2. Then click 'Go to **NAME_OF_FUNCTION**'

[image]

3. Sometimes you'll be asked to type '**Continue**'.

After that you'll be able to execute your scripts.